# Un-migrating a post

Tags: discussion, migration

I had an answer to a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/508600/specifically-define-colors-of-bars-in-histogram) which was recently migrated to SuperUser.  I'm not completely sure why the question was migrated from StackOverflow.  Is there a way to get an explanation as to why it was migrated?  Is there a way to vote to move it back to StackOverflow?

I think that the question is perfectly appropriate for StackOverflow because it is a question about how to accomplish a particular task in `gnuplot` -- which is a scripted plotting utility (i.e. a very special purpose programming language).  If this question belongs on SuperUser, then pretty much every other gnuplot question on StackOverflow should be migrated as well.

As a side note, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/508644/looking-up-gnuplot-abbreviations) was also moved -- presumably in the same time range (and I'm not sure why).

Comment: Of the 5 people who voted on your question 2 don't have an account on SU, 2 only have account association bonus and the last has 131 rep - they are clearly qualified to decide that SU is the correct place for your question - NOT!

Answer (score 3):

Flag the question (at either end) for moderator attention. Though it might be simpler to flag the question at the target end. The moderators on the two sites can then coordinate their actions.

The target site mods can reject the migration by closing/deleting the question. This will reset the question on the source site to being closed as "Off Topic".

The source site mods can then reopen the question.

*The above assumed that the moderators agree that the question shouldn't have been migrated of course.*

Comment: I don't have a SuperUser account, so I can't flag it as I don't have the Rep there.  When I click on the question at the SO end, it takes me to the SU end.

Comment: @mgilson - click on the "migrated from" link on the Super User question

Comment: Thanks.  I've flagged it (on the SO end).  I suppose we'll see what the mods think :)

Comment: @mgilson you got more than 200 rep on Stack Overflow so once you log into Super User using the same OpenID provider the account will be automatically associated and you will get +100 bonus, starting with shiny 101 reputation which is more than enough to flag. :) (You can see it here on Meta, you got +100 when you joined in July 11th)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd -- Thanks for the comment.  (I couldn't remember how much rep is required to flag -- or if you just need an account).  However, joining over there just so I can flag something which I believe is wrong that happened on this end is a bit flaky, don't you think?

Comment: @mgilson not at all. Many users create account on virtually *all* the sites just for fun and can't see any wrong in that. Putting this extreme case aside, having to flag a post is totally valid reason to "join" a site.